# How do I unlock all the pardners?

Tags: west-of-loathing

After the prologue in boring springs, you can take one of 4 pardners with you to the main game.
I've unlocked Crazy Pete by giving him mining things and Susie by returning her rifle, but who are the other two pardners and how do I unlock them?

[image]

Comment: Aww crap I unlocked one you don't have but I can't remember who it is because I didn't take them with me.

Comment: @ash when you start a new character you can skip the prologue and it presents this selection screen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the pardners that you're missing is Doc Alice. To unlock her, you must talk to the hostler to send him to the horsery. After that, talk to the bartender to unlock the basement. In the basement, there's a crate where you can get a bottle of Nurse Whiskey. Once you get the bottle, talk to the hostler and ask about his injuries. Then, you can go to Doc Alice's house, give her the whiskey and, go through her dialogue to unlock the option to take her on your journey.

The other pardner that you're missing is Gary. He's a goblin. To unlock him, follow the instructions above to unlock Doc Alice with the important caveat that you do **not** fight the goblin in the basement. Once you gain access to Doc Alice's house, interact with her bookshelf to learn Goblintongue. After that, go down to the basement, talk with Gary and, you can take him with you to Dustwater.

Comment: could you add how to get the other 2 as well? as the question does ask how to unlock all of them

Answer (score -1):

Another one is **Gary the Goblin**.

To unlock him you have to:

1. Unlock Doc Alice's quest,
2. Read the book on her shelf, the one about Goblintongue,
3. Don't kill him.